# Regex: Extract all elements that contain a that contain a specific letter from a string

Tags: python, regex, string

I am building a simple equation solver and have trouble isolating the elements. Basically, there are two type of elements: integers (-12, +9) and variables (-3x, -7x, -2x). The first step of my strategy is to isolate these two different types of elements using a regex:

```
import re

t = 'x - 3x -7x+9-2x-12 = 42'
t = t.replace(' ','')
if ((t[0]) != '-' and not t[0] == '+'): #add trailing plus if necessary
    t = '+'+t
print(t)

print(re.findall(r"([+-]+(\d+)+[x])", t))
```

My regex has two problems:

1. It returns a list of tuples

   [('-3x', '3'), ('-7x', '7'), ('-2x', '2')]

   instead of a list: ['x', '-3x', '-7x', '-2x']
2. It omits the first element because there is no digit (2x would work).

Thank you for your help!

P.S.: I am confident, that with some research I can write the regex to extract the numbers-only elements (-12, +9), but I am really stuck with this one.

Comment: Use [`re.findall(r'[+-]?\d*x', t)`](https://regex101.com/r/CFoICO/1) to get  `['x', '-3x', '-7x', '-2x']`. Not sure about the numbers, but try [`re.findall(r'[-+]?\b\d+\b(?!$)', t)`](https://regex101.com/r/CFoICO/2).

Comment: Should 42 be included in the final list ?

Comment: Is the variable always `x` or can other characters be used like `a` or even `α`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - that did the trick! thanks

Comment: @ctwheels - ideally, it should be other characters as well

Comment: Then replace `x` with `[a-z]`.

Comment: You may also use `[+-]?\d*[^\W_\d]` to match non-ASCII letters like `α`

Comment: @NathanBlaine - no. I am treating the left and right sides of the equation separately first and then do the switch by * (-1)

Comment: @all: Thank you for your great input - you were all very kind and helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the "variables", you may use

```
re.findall(r'[+-]?\d*[a-z]', t)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CFoICO/3).

**Details**

- `[+-]?` - an optional `-` or `+` chars
- `\d*` - 0+ digits
- `[a-z]` - any lowercase ASCII letter (add `+` to match 1 or more of them).

To obtain the integers without including the last number (after `=`), you may use

```
re.findall(r'[-+]?\b\d+\b(?!$)', t)
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CFoICO/2).

**Details**

- `[-+]?` - an optional `+` or `-`
- `\b\d+\b` - 1+ digits as a whole word
- `(?!$)` - not at the end of the string. If there can be trailing whitespace, replace with `(?!\s*$)`.